# unable to load bundle.js using cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova

I don't understand why cordova doesn't load my bundle.js file.
The bundle.js is built with webpack.

index.html

[image: index.html]

cordova run browser

[image: cordova run browser]

file structure

[image: file structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bundle.js is also `JavaScript` so you need to change type to `text/javascript`